# Using OpenStack on AKS, OpenStack seems to be in a strange state after stopping and starting all VMs

Tags: openstack

Created an OpenStack CLI on AKS as follows:

```
$ kubectl create configmap openstack-rc-os-cli-0 --from-file=$OPENSTACK_RC
```

$OPENSTACK_RC is a file containing the following:

```
export OS_USERNAME="$OPENSTACK_USER"
export OS_PROJECT_NAME="$OPENSTACK_TENANT"
export OS_AUTH_URL="http://$DEVSTACK_PRIVATE_IP/identity"
export OS_PASSWORD="$OPENSTACK_PASS"
export OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME=default
export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID=default
```

Then:

```
$ kubectl create -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: os-cli-0
spec:
  containers:
  - name: openstack-cli
    image: alpine
    volumeMounts:
    - name: openstack-rc-os-cli-0
      mountPath: /openstack
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args:
      - -c
      - apk update && \
        apk add python3 && \
        apk add py3-pip && \
        apk add python3-dev && \
        apk add gcc && \
        apk add musl-dev && \
        apk add libffi-dev && \
        apk add openssl-dev && \
        pip3 install python-openstackclient && \
        sh -c 'echo ". /openstack/openstack_rc" >> /root/.profile; while true; do sleep 60; done;'
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
    - name: openstack-rc-os-cli-0
      configMap:
        name: openstack-rc-os-cli-0
        defaultMode: 0755
EOF
```

Then I deployed a number of services and all was well.

Then I decided that Azure was costing too much money to keep the AKS VMs running all the time, so stopped all of the VMs.  When I brought them back up, a lot of my pods did not come up properly.  In particular, the os-cli-0 pod is showing simply "Error":

```
$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME       READY   STATUS   RESTARTS   AGE   IP       NODE                       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
os-cli-0   0/1     Error    0          9d    <none>   aks-nodepool1-39561274-1   <none>           <none>
```

I looked at the logs for this pod, and there was literally nothing in there other than what was there from when I first built it.  This leads me to believe that the pod never even tried to start after the VMs came back up.

Azure reports that AKS is working properly and as far as I can tell it is.  The problem seems to be that OpenStack has not started back up properly.

I am probably just missing something stupid and I appreciate any help.

Comment: You say that OpenStack is in a strange state, but you show no evidence of that. You do show that a pod on which you installed the openstack client doesn't start. If the logs are empty, try `kubectl describe pod os-cli-0` for more information about that pod.

Comment: A potentially related piece of information: When you restart Devstack, don't expect OpenStack to be fully functional. Devstack has not been designed for rebooting; it's original purpose is quickly spinning up a cloud for testing OpenStack code. After rebooting a Devstack server, you will have to fix networking and volume storage as a minimum.

Comment: Also, what prevents you from deleting the OpenStack CLI pod and starting it again? It doesn't seem to contain any data worth saving.